# NSURLRequest for JSON w/ credentials

Tags: objective-c, json, basic-authentication, credentials, nsurlrequest

```
NSString *login = @"Web Guest";
NSString *password = @"xxxxx";
NSError *myError = nil;

NSLog(@"CONNECTION: Adding credentials");

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:login
                                                         password:password
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                         initWithHost:@"54.225.xxx.xxx"
                                         port:80
                                         protocol:@"http"
                                         realm:@"54.225.xxx.xxx" 
                                         authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];

//Not sure if set up correctly

[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];   

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/blah"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:12];

NSLog(@"CONNECTION: Running request");

//Perform the request
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
                sendSynchronousRequest:request
                returningResponse:&response
                error:&myError];
```

> At this point, I get an error "Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' +[NSString
>   stringWithCString:encoding:]: NULL cString'"

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Webserver response: %@", result);
```

I'm attempting to return some JSON from the web server which requires authorization using basic authentication, but seem to be having some trouble with getting it set up. I'm new to objective-c programming and ios development, but would really appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: This means either `data` is `nil` or the data isn't a valid string with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Check if `data == nil` and if it is, print `myError`. - Note that you should not use `stringWithCString` to convert the data to a string, because the data is not NUL-terminated. Use `NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a scheme in your request URL string: @"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/blah". You'll need something like @"https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/blah", otherwise [NSURL URLWithString:] returns nil.